# Windows command not finding script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command

I am working on the password locker project in the Automate the boring stuff with Python book. I need to create a script and a bat file to run the program with a Windows command. When running the command, Windows informs me that it can't find my script ("pw") and to check the name & try again.

The folder where the script it located has been added to the Path system variable folder.

Here is my script file (pw.py):

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'f7nsdkfn2BDD3fkjTXjs6Fjsn',
             'blog': 'fdkNc32NskNskKslLI321n',
             'luggage': 12345}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password")
sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
  pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
  print("Password for " + account + " copied to clipboard")
else:
  print("There is no account named " + account)
```

Here is my bat file (MyName is my real name):

```
@py.exe C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\MyScripts\pw.py %*
@pause
```

And here are the path folders I have added to both the system and user variables:

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\MyScripts
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
```

Could you help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Sadly, I believe your obfuscation is to blame. Does `MyName` actually contain a space? If so, or in any case, `"quote the filename"` ie,  use `py.exe "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\MyScripts\pw.py" %*` - and always best to report the *precise* (If obfuscated)  error message - saves us guessing.

Comment: `sys.exit()` is indented incorrectly, I assume. Doesn't that belong to the if-clause?

Comment: The issue came from the user (me). I was calling my .py file instead of my .bat in my Windows command. Thanks for the help! You asnwers helped me with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Add double apostrophes and include the full python file path. The following worked for me:

```
@"C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\test.py" %*
@pause
```

Comment: I found how to fix the issue, and feel extremely silly. In the command file, I was calling for the .py instead of the .bat file. Can't believe I spend hours modifying codes and doing system restore for this. 

Thanks for everyone who helped!

If someone else does this problem, the command might not work if the bat file end with * instead of one (this information is not written in the book).
Wrong code:
'@py.exe C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\MyScripts\pw.py %*'

Good code
'@py.exe C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\MyScripts\pw.py %1'

Comment: Great to hear that you were able to fix it!